# Jquery Sortable - Replacing Items rather than swapping items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any configurable option to achieve the feature like replacing the list items rather than swapping items in JQuery Sortable UI. Current feature is like Item1 Swaps with Item2 and vice versa. I need a feature like, If item2 is dragged and dropped on Item1, item2 should replace Item1 and Item2 position will be empty. Any help? thanks.

Comment: You can always bind to the drag/drop events and handle it yourself...

Comment: You probably would be better off using draggable and dropable rather than sortable.

Comment: @Brad Christie: I couldn't find any drap/drop events for Jquery Sortable in the documentation. Can you briefly explain plz. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following code:

```
$('#container').sortable({
  connectWith: '#container',
  items: '.children', //#container > .children
  cursor: 'move',
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var item = $(ui.item);
    var sender = $(ui.sender);
    sender.append(item.siblings('.children'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/CZm9C/2/

Now drag from first box to the second. Hope this helps and please let me know if I missed anything, :)

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".leftDiv .item").draggable({
        helper: function(ev, ui) {
            return "<span class='helperPick'>"+$(this).html()+"</span>";
        },
        connectToSortable: ".rightDiv"
    });

    $(".rightDiv").sortable({
        'items': ".item",
        'receive': function(event, ui){
            // find the class of the dropped ui, look for the one with the integer suffix.
            var clazz = getClassNameWithNumberSuffix(ui.item);
            $('.leftDiv .' + clazz).draggable( "option", "revert", true )
            if($('.rightDiv .' + clazz).length > 1){
                $('.rightDiv .' + clazz + ':not(:first)').remove();    

            }
            $('.leftDiv .' + clazz).remove();
        }
    });

});

function getClassNameWithNumberSuffix(el) {
  var className = null;
  var regexp = /\w+\d+/;
  $($(el).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() {
    if (regexp.test(this)) {
      className = this;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return className;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftDiv"> drag to ==>
    <div class="item item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item item4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item item5">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item item6">Item 6</div>
</div>
<div class="rightDiv"> ==> To this
     <div class="item item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item item3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item item4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item item5">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item item6">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftDiv, .rightDiv {width:120px; float:left; border:1px solid #000; padding:5px; margin:10px; min-height:130px}
.rightDiv {margin-left:40px}

.item {height:20px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #EEE; background-color:#FFF}

.helperPick {border:1px dashed red; height:20px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; width:120px}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and help. I am really looking this feature within  the Sortable rather than dragging from draggable item connected to Sortable list. I was able to hide the placeholder and get the feel of replacement but unfortunately i am not able to identify the index of drop location to replace.On drop, for me receive method itself is not calling. Thanks.